# Optimize way to query over 50 million data records in SQLite DB using C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a database including data size of 11GB. In my scenario, I need to query those all data (`select * from table`) and create objects using each 50 million records. Here memory is not a problem, I'm using 8CPU 52GB RAM machine.

Currently, I'm doing this job as this, get the number of CPU in the machine as threads and divide the database into ranges for each thread. Then in each thread, it queries the data in SQLite data records and creates an `std::vector<map <string,string>>`structure to save those data. Then get one by one element from the vector and create an object that I need. Finally, all threads push the objects into the global array for all threads.

But this method, not giving expecting optimization results for over 50Million records, anyone can suggest me what to do for gain the quick access of data from DB.

**Note - I saw that there is a method called MapReduce. But I can't understand how to apply it to my scenario.**

Comment: Is the db a bottleneck or the disk access ? My sugestion is to use a ram disk.

Comment: "Quick access of data from DB" is hard to reconcile with copying 50 million records. It's not something that can be easily fixed by changing a bit of code.

Comment: You should check is that the functions you are using to read from the database are thread safe and able to be called by multiple threads at the same time.  If not then each of your threads will just be waiting on the other and you would basically have a serial approach.

Comment: Why do you need to create those records as C++ objects? Why not use the very heavily optimised features of SQLite to access them via SQLite?

Comment: @NathanOliver here threads are working fine. This gives better results for 50,000 records.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Acually, I need to create python interface using boost::python. The accessible method of data is as objects. That's why I need those records as objects. BTW, can you please explain me very heavily optimised features of SQLite to access them via SQLite

Comment: Why do you need to read *all* records and construct *all* objects up front? Can't you simply create them lazily as they are needed so you only need to fetch/convert one (or a few) record(s) at a time from the DB?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest the following:

1. make sure you build in release mode with -O2
2. run a profiler (e.g. http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy/) on your code to see where the bottleneck is
3. compare single and multithread solution

possible actions (depending where your bottleneck is)

- do/start conversion while reading
- try single thread to rule out problems with locking/shared data structures
- use cache-friendly data structures
- make bulk operations for processing
  ...

tell your findings after profiling and you'll get more targeted advice